# How do I remove Image and Table option from TinyMCE textarea?

Tags: plugins, tinymce, rich-text-editor

Everytime I click inside the textarea to type, these two options show up. I don't need them. I tried looking on the TinyMCE website but couldn't find anything. Hoping someone could help me find a solution.

[image]

Here is my tinyMCE.js code

```
var useDarkMode = window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)").matches;

[tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    plugins:
        "print preview paste importcss searchreplace autolink autosave save directionality code visualblocks visualchars fullscreen codesample charmap hr nonbreaking toc insertdatetime advlist lists wordcount imagetools textpattern noneditable help charmap quickbars emoticons",
    toolbar: "undo redo | charmap emoticons | bold italic",
    toolbar_sticky: true,
    autosave_ask_before_unload: true,
    autosave_interval: "30s",
    autosave_prefix: "{path}{query}-{id}-",
    autosave_restore_when_empty: false,
    autosave_retention: "2m",
    image_advtab: true,
    branding: false,
    link_list: \[
        { title: "My page 1", value: "https://www.tiny.cloud" },
        { title: "My page 2", value: "http://www.moxiecode.com" },
    \],
    image_list: \[
        { title: "My page 1", value: "https://www.tiny.cloud" },
        { title: "My page 2", value: "http://www.moxiecode.com" },
    \],
    image_class_list: \[
        { title: "None", value: "" },
        { title: "Some class", value: "class-name" },
    \],
    importcss_append: true,

    template_cdate_format: "\[Date Created (CDATE): %m/%d/%Y : %H:%M:%S\]",
    template_mdate_format: "\[Date Modified (MDATE): %m/%d/%Y : %H:%M:%S\]",
    height: 300,
    image_caption: true,
    quickbars_selection_toolbar: "bold italic | h2 h3 blockquote",
    noneditable_noneditable_class: "mceNonEditable",
    toolbar_mode: "sliding",
    skin: useDarkMode ? "oxide-dark" : "oxide",
    content_css: useDarkMode ? "dark" : "default",
    content_style:
        "body { background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3); color: #ebfdffff; font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px }",
    oninit: "postInitWork",
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need to remove `quickbars` from `plugins`.

Here is the codepen for demostration:
https://codepen.io/michael-vascue/pen/MWpOmVB?editors=1011

```js
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea#basic-example",
    height: 500,
    menubar: false,
     plugins:
        "print preview paste importcss searchreplace autolink autosave save directionality code visualblocks visualchars fullscreen codesample charmap hr nonbreaking toc insertdatetime advlist lists wordcount imagetools textpattern noneditable help charmap  emoticons",
    toolbar: "undo redo | charmap emoticons | bold italic",
    toolbar_sticky: true,
    autosave_ask_before_unload: true,
    autosave_interval: "30s",
    autosave_prefix: "{path}{query}-{id}-",
    autosave_restore_when_empty: false,
    autosave_retention: "2m",
    image_advtab: true,
    branding: false,
    link_list: [
        { title: "My page 1", value: "https://www.tiny.cloud" },
        { title: "My page 2", value: "http://www.moxiecode.com" },
    ],
    image_list: [
        { title: "My page 1", value: "https://www.tiny.cloud" },
        { title: "My page 2", value: "http://www.moxiecode.com" },
    ],
    image_class_list: [
        { title: "None", value: "" },
        { title: "Some class", value: "class-name" },
    ],
    importcss_append: true,
    template_cdate_format: "\[Date Created (CDATE): %m/%d/%Y : %H:%M:%S\]",
    template_mdate_format: "\[Date Modified (MDATE): %m/%d/%Y : %H:%M:%S\]",
    height: 300,
    image_caption: true,
    quickbars_selection_toolbar: "bold italic | h2 h3 blockquote",
    noneditable_noneditable_class: "mceNonEditable",
    toolbar_mode: "sliding",
    skin: "oxide-dark",
    content_css: "dark",
    content_style:
        "body { background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3); color: #ebfdffff; font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px }",
    oninit: "postInitWork"
});
```

Comment: Worth noting that will disable all quickbars. It looks like the OP wants the selection toolbar still, so it might be better to just disable the insert toolbar: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/opensource/quickbars/#quickbars_insert_toolbar

Comment: Disabling the quickbar insert toolbar also works but I don't need the selection toolbar so it does not matter to me. For someone who still wants a quick selection toolbar to bold, italicize text then they should use this method.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `quickbars_insert_toolbar: ''` in `tinymce.init`

Comment: This worked for me as I wanted to keep the quickbar but just wanted to remove image and table tooltip, so this worked for me.
Thanks for the answer